# Principal axis form (quadratic) to hyperbola/ellipse form?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How is the [principal axis form (quadratic)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_axis_theorem#Motivation) of a symmetric orthogonally diagonalized matrix

e.g.

$$y^2+6yx+x^2=1$$

transformed into the equation of a hyperbola (or ellipse as well)?

Completing the square?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do what the link you posted says:

$$1=x^2+6xy+y^2=(x\;y)\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&1\end{pmatrix}\binom xy=\binom xy^tA\binom xy$$

Diagonalize orthogonally the matrix $\;A\;$ (it's possible because it is symmetric):

$$\begin{vmatrix}x-1&-3\\-3&x-1\end{vmatrix}=x^2-2x-8=(x-4)(x+2)$$

Now eigenvectors:

$$\lambda=-2:\;\;\;\;-3x-3y=0\implies x=-y\implies\binom 1{\!\!-1}$$

$$\lambda=4:\;\;\;\;3x-3y=0\implies x=y\implies\binom 1{1}$$

With $\;P=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{pmatrix}\;$ , you can already check that $\;P^{-1}AP=\begin{pmatrix}-2&0\\0&4\end{pmatrix}=:D\;$ , but we want to do that with orthogonal matrix $\;Q\;$ , so we apply Gram Schmidt to this matrix's columns, but this is very easy in this case as both columns of $\;P\;$ are already orthogonal, so we only have to divide by their length:

$$u_1:=\frac{\binom{\;1}{-1}}{\left\|\binom{\;1}{-1}\right\|}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\binom{\;1}{-1}\;,\;\;u_2=\frac{\binom11}{\left\|\binom11\right\|}=\frac1{\sqrt2}\binom11$$

And now we get

$$Q:=\begin{pmatrix}\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\\-\frac1{\sqrt2}&\frac1{\sqrt2}\end{pmatrix}=\frac1{\sqrt2}P\;,\;\;\text{and}\;\;Q^{-1}AQ=D\implies A=QDQ^{-1}=QDQ^t$$

since $\;Q\;$ is orthogonal and thus $\;Q^{-1}=Q^t\;$ , and then finally, using $\;\vec a:=\binom xy\;$ , we get

$$1=\vec a^tA\vec a=\vec a^t\left(QDQ^{-1}\right)\vec a=\left(Q^t\vec a\right)^tD\left(Q^t\vec a\right)=-2\left(\frac{x-y}{\sqrt2}\right)^2+4\left(\frac{x+y}{\sqrt2}\right)^2$$

so we have a hyperbola here